# Recover BTC sent to a BCC address

Tags: address, bitcoin-cash, wallet-recovery, cross-chain-recovery

I accidentally sent my BTC to a BCC address. Is there a way to recover them? Is there somebody that can help me with this matter? If there is a charge to recover my coins, I will pay for it.